# Object initialization in Java

Tags: java, constructor

Consider following code.

```
public class Skyler {
Skyler s1=new Skyler();
public static void main(String asd[]){
         Skyler s2=new Skyler();
    }
}
```

It generates `java.lang.StackOverflowError` Exception. Why?

Consider following code also.

```
public class Skyler {
    Skyler s1=new Skyler();
    static Skyler s2=new Skyler();
    Skyler(){
        System.out.println("const");
    }
    public static void main(String sdp[]){}
}
```

This is also generating same `java.lang.StackOverflowError` exception. Why?

Is reason same for both Exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are undergone a loop where the constructor calling it self for servaral times until it's overflowed.

For ex :

[image]

And the reason is same in both cases. It's calling it self endlessly.

In your both cases there is only once difference that you provided a default no org constructor with a print statement so that you can see that print statement until you got the **error**.

Comment: How come is it an ERROR ? Is it not an Exception?

Comment: @prateektomar No. There is a difference between error and exception.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you create an instance of `Skyler`, the `s1` member of that instance is initialized, which creates another instance of `Skyler`, which initializes the `s1` member of that other instance, which creates another instance of `Skyler` and so on...

In other words, you have an infinite chain of calls to the `Skyler` constructor, which causes `StackOverflowErr`.

Comment: Is reason same for exceptions in both the code snippets?

Comment: @prateektomar Yes. It is. Added that in my answer. Please read.

Comment: @prateektomar Yes. The only difference between the two snippets is where the first instance of `Skyler` is created (in the main method in the first snippet and in the initialization of a static variable in the second snippet). Once that takes place, the initialization `Skyler s1=new Skyler();` causes the infinite constructor calls leading to the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `Skyler s1=new Skyler();`.With your code,Skyler class has a variable whose type is Skyler,then it will be create a Skyler again and again,so `StackOverflowException` exists.

Answer (score 1):

Check the logic, you create a new `Skyler`, what does this do? It creates a new `Skyler`, surprisingly this new `Skyler` creates another new `Skyler`. This all comes from your line `Skyler s1=new Skyler();`(the one that is not static), which recursivly creates endles instances of the Object `Skyler`.

Answer (score 1):

The class Skyler calls its own constructor. So while creating an instance of Skyler, another instance of Skyler is created and so on... the result is a StackOverflow.